# Looking for code to update a textbox on a SpreadsheetML doc (client using VB.Net but I can read and convert C#)

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office, openxml-sdk

I have a 2010 Excel Spreadsheet (OpenXML) with a textbox "LengthVariableTextBox" on it. I wish to change the textbox value (currently @@.@ just as a placeholder) using the openxml SDK with VB.Net (perfered) or C#. Below is a XML fragment from drawing7.xml showing the textbox.

Thanks for the Help!

M. Scott Blalock

```
  <xdr:twoCellAnchor>
     <xdr:from>
       <xdr:col>2</xdr:col>
       <xdr:colOff>502920</xdr:colOff>
       <xdr:row>8</xdr:row>
       <xdr:rowOff>45720</xdr:rowOff>
     </xdr:from>
     <xdr:to>
       <xdr:col>3</xdr:col>
       <xdr:colOff>510540</xdr:colOff>
       <xdr:row>9</xdr:row>
       <xdr:rowOff>76200</xdr:rowOff>
     </xdr:to>
     <xdr:sp macro="" textlink="">
       <xdr:nvSpPr>
         <xdr:cNvPr id="287" name="3:24 PM 9/19/2012" />
         <xdr:cNvSpPr txBox="1" />
       </xdr:nvSpPr>
       <xdr:spPr>
         <a:xfrm>
           <a:off x="1722120" y="1386840" />
           <a:ext cx="617220" cy="198120" />
         </a:xfrm>
         <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
           <a:avLst />
         </a:prstGeom>
         <a:solidFill>
           <a:schemeClr val="tx1" />
         </a:solidFill>
         <a:ln w="9525" cmpd="sng">
           <a:solidFill>
             <a:schemeClr val="lt1">
               <a:shade val="50000" />
             </a:schemeClr>
           </a:solidFill>
         </a:ln>
       </xdr:spPr>
       <xdr:style>
         <a:lnRef idx="0">
           <a:scrgbClr r="0" g="0" b="0" />
         </a:lnRef>
         <a:fillRef idx="0">
           <a:scrgbClr r="0" g="0" b="0" />
         </a:fillRef>
         <a:effectRef idx="0">
           <a:scrgbClr r="0" g="0" b="0" />
         </a:effectRef>
         <a:fontRef idx="minor">
           <a:schemeClr val="dk1" />
         </a:fontRef>
       </xdr:style>
       <xdr:txBody>
         <a:bodyPr vertOverflow="clip" wrap="square" rtlCol="0" anchor="t" />
         <a:lstStyle />
         <a:p>
           <a:r>
             <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1100">
               <a:solidFill>
                 <a:schemeClr val="bg1" />
               </a:solidFill>
             </a:rPr>
             <a:t>@@.@</a:t>
           </a:r>
         </a:p>
       </xdr:txBody>
     </xdr:sp>
     <xdr:clientData />
   </xdr:twoCellAnchor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/3eb9075a-de13-4f4a-a83d-c42cdb6b8e98